# how to reference URL into Vue.Component.Template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How to refer URL into Vue.Template link.
Template is longer and all operations are going to include to mounted/methods.

```
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: './views/templatebutton.html'   //how to refer URL here.
})
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/2015/10/28/why-no-template-url/

Comment: use single file component if you're using Vue cli

Comment: Using .NET MVC existing project and it does not include webpack so, .vue file would not support.

Comment: Is it possible to use ASP.NET MVC (existing app) + VUEJS with single componenet. without including webpack/npm ? Or its fine if this can be dune with nuget.. any reference link would be appreciated if that is feasible.

Comment: For existing MVC project,  to allow single component file, Do I have to add "Webpack" package only, right ? is there also need any other package. here, need to use existing bootstrap and other JS reference from "_Layout.cshtml" as layout is already existed and same will be reference to new razor view and that view will be using with Vue JS. Can you please advise here, would it be able to use existing _Layout and all bootstrap & other CSS references into single componenet

Answer (score 1):

You could read the local HTML file as a string, and then load the result into the `template` field. With a module loader (such as [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)), you would use `require()` to import the HTML file:

```js
// Foo.js
Vue.component('button-counter', {
  template: require('./views/templatebutton.html')
})
```

Alternatively, if [`vue-loader`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/) is available to your project, you could use single file components, which allow importing the template from an external file:

```
<!-- Foo.vue -->
<template src="./views/templatebutton.html" />
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/3q5y7p4p5q)

Comment: For existing MVC project, to allow single component file, is there only require "Webpack.Net" package Or is there also need any other package. In this MVC 5 app, need to use existing bootstrap and other JS reference from "_Layout.cshtml" as layout is already existed and same will be reference to new razor view file (that is going to use with Vue JS). Can you please advise here, would it be able to use existing _Layout and all bootstrap & other CSS references into single component file. and which other package should be consider for basic setup of vue JS and single component file.

Comment: You would also need `vue-loader` and several other packages. Refer to this [Medium post](https://medium.com/corebuild-software/vue-js-and-net-mvc-b5cede228626) on how to integrate Webpack with ASP.NET.

Comment: ok, do I have to use npm ? I could not find "vue-loader" in nuget package manager. Its only using nuget manager/package.config so, npm would not be feasible as per existing project setup.

Comment: Yes, you'll need `npm`. which is also available on NuGet.

Comment: Not sure to include npm as Nuget already there. But right, its for javascript package manager so some depedency would need addition to nuget package. will check if that feasible for existing project to include new package manager. Else, will go with VueJS and not .vue file.  For Now, included webpack.net and reference to "r.js" but require(".html file path") statement getting error as ` file has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: Webpack supports `require` out of the box. `r.js` isn't needed (and would conflict with Webpack's `require`).

Answer (score 0):

I solve this limitation using [requirejs](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles) (
although it is not recommended).

You can load the text from html file by adding `'text!'` before the template url and load it as text like:

```
var template = require('text!/assets/vuejs/controllers/venda_direta/cart.html');
```

and then use it as your template string:

```
...    
    template : template
...
```