# How do I include external templates in Vue.js using a CDN?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Trying to essentially replace my `const Product` with an external file.

I would like to do that to make it easier to edit the template. What is the easiest way?

CDN:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>`

Vue JS:

```
<script>
    const Product = {template: `<div class="user"> <h2>User {{ $route.params.id }}</h2></div> `}

    const router = new VueRouter({

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/product/:id', component: Product, 
        }
    ],

    mode: 'history',

    })

    const app = new Vue({ 
        router 
    })

    .$mount('#app')

</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52239850/3226121) and [this github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6424).

Comment: That is for the CLI, not CDN. Thanks for the link though!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :)